# Login multiple web applications (php) by SSO using WSO2 IS

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have several web aplicaciones (PHP) that requires a control roles to access them. The roles are defined in WSO2 Identity Server, my problem is how to communicate web applications to access them at managing the identity server and if that can be done with the WSO2 Web Services Framework for PHP or need something more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simplesamlphp [1] with WSO2 Identity server[2] to get SSO to your application.
[1] https://simplesamlphp.org/
[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/SAML2+IdP+with+SimpleSAMLphp+Service+Provider